# Dotnet new project cannot run

Tags: c#, .net, linux, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I (almost) try to get an helloworld with dotnet cli on Linux. In fact I simply try to create a MVC project.

I installed (and reinstall multiple times during this process) dotnet-sdk-bin from AUR.

- dotnet new mvc -n foo
- cd foo/
- dotnet run

### Result :

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
> The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
>
> - No frameworks were found.
>   You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
>   The specified framework can be found at:
> - [https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&>framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=manjaro-x64](https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&%3Eframework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=manjaro-x64)

### dotnet --info :

[image]

I also tried with and without dotnet-runtim-bin and dotnet-host-bin but the result remain the same. Also found [this thread on github](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3487) but it didn't help me that much.

Comment: Did you go to the download link it suggested (and install it)?

Comment: I tried scripting install and got the same result. Try manual install then it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the runtime to the AspNetCore, I'm sure that you have the runtime to the .NETCORE, but the Asp is a separate runtime and you need to install, I share the URL https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

NOTE: Remember before you type dotnet run is a good practice dotnet build it's help you to find any break references in your code or any lost library.

Comment: Actually dotnet build was working fine, all reference seems good. But as you said I needed AspNetCore AND .NETCore, which.. for whatever reason is not reference as a dependencies in the Arch User Repository, nether in the install scrit give by Microsoft itself.

Only a fully manual installation resolve my probleme

Comment: verify if you have the different paths
.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]